# What is a Rich Media Assset Content Type?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type

I want to create a Content Type based on Videos, but I noticed three Content Types in the Digital Asset Content Type Group.  Video, Video Rendition, and Rich Media Asset.

Does anyone know the difference among these?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rich Media Asset Content type is inherited from Document and contains some metadatas for rich media, for example, image, video, audio.
[image]

Video Rendition is inherited from Rich Media asset content type, and used to link to a video file to play.
[image]

Video is System Media Collection which is built in by system.

When you create a Asset library, it will contains the following content types by default:
[image]

If you upload a video into it in SharePoint Online, you will see it shows as folder:
[image]

Click the folder, you will see:
[image]

Comment: Is it still the recommended way to go with modern? I've read in several places that a plain document library should be used for videos and pictures. /?